# Please guide me on how to implement Unit of Work Pattern in eShopOnWeb project?

Tags: .net-core, design-patterns, entity-framework-core, architecture, clean-architecture

I am developing an application in .NET Core 7 by following the eShopOnWeb Clean Architecture https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb. I found the application is missing implementation of UoW. I need to add UoW so that I could commit/roll back the transaction. Please guide me on how I could add the UoW pattern without compromising the structure of the clean architecture.

Thanks.